# TelephonyManager instantiation

Tags: android, android-context, telephonymanager

I can't seem to be able to declare a TelephonyManager in android, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
TelephonyManager tele = Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your forgetting to cast. It should look like this:

```
TelephonyManager tele = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Also, if we are not in an activity, we need to call it like this:
`TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);`